# Laravel Permission denied error on Linux Server

Tags: linux, laravel

I am facing a very strange error with my Laravel application on the production server (Linux). Whenever the users of my application login for the first time in morning, they get a permission denied error which read something like

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/PROJECT/storage/framework/cache/data/0c/e5/0ce52dca12715a327eb4c1b4bff36293ea67c719): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

To overcome this, the first thing I have to do in the morning is to give permission to the entire project by

```
sudo chmod -R 777 PROJECT
```

And then it runs just fine.
This is slowly getting very annoying as it is happening every morning. Why are the permissions getting revoked automatically and is there a permanent solution for this?

Please help me and thank you all in advance

Comment: Are you maybe deploying your application via a CI pipeline? Maybe the user from the pipeline is different from the user running the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your application run some command also. That's why your storage permission is overrated by system user. (by which user cron execute).

The thing is, `storage` directory should have write access to both system user and webserver(apache/nginx)

BTW, Symfony framework has some nice solution for this kind of situation which also can be application in Laravel Application.

Please look at this:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

In your case, this command would be like:

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)

sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX /var/www/html/PROJECT/storage

sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX /var/www/html/PROJECT/storage
```

You can also achieve above solution if you know know what is your webserver user.

```
sudo chown -R "$local_user":"$webserver_user" "/var/www/html/PROJECT/storage"
sudo chmod -R 0777 "/var/www/html/PROJECT/storage"
```

If my opinion, `setfacl` is better solution if you have `setfacl` installed in your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your webserver has enough permission to the directory instead of giving 777 to the project as this is your production environment which is not at all recommendable.

Also try php artisan cache:clear